# three20 image Gallery,tabbar

Tags: objective-c, xcode

is there any tutorial to add three20 image gallery in tab bar...i was successful as far as the image gallery is concerned.could you guys help me to add dis in a tab bar

Answer (score 1):

> Regarding the tabbar-based app, note in this example we were using the
>   TTNavigator to display our PhotoViewController, but you don’t have to.
>   PhotoViewController is a plain old View Controller, so you can add it
>   to one of your tabs just by setting it in Interface Builder, for
>   example.

Source : http://www.raywenderlich.com/1430/how-to-use-the-three20-photo-viewer